# Can js forEach take other inputs

Tags: javascript

```js
function addToArr(num, arr) {
  arr.push(num);
}
theArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
myArr = [];
theArr.forEach(addToArr(ele, theArr));

console.log(myArr);
```

I wanted to write a function that could be used in a forEach() that could take a different array as a parameter - that I could push to.

Comment: `forEach` expects a function as a parameter. `addToArr(ele, myArr)` isn’t a function, it’s `undefined`.

Comment: `arr.forEach(function(ele){ addToArr(ele, myArr); });` should work

Comment: also, the arguments to the callback are `item, index, array`

Answer (score 3):

The parameter you pass to `forEach` must be a function, meaning your `addToArr` needs to return a function. This is often called currying, partial application, or a closure.

```js
function addToArr(arr) {
  return function(num) {
    arr.push(num);
  };
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var myArr = [];

arr.forEach(addToArr(myArr));

console.log(myArr);
```

In ES6 it's much easier to write with arrow functions.

```
const addToArr = arr => num => arr.push(num);
```

Comment: Or (more commonly), wrap the function call in a function.

Comment: Thanks for that @4castle - elegantly written. I will have to study it to fully grasp it all.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the second argument to `forEach` is used as the `this` value in the passed callback, so the following should work as well:

```js
function addToArray (x) {
  this.push(x)
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var otherArray = []
array.forEach(addToArray, otherArray)

console.log(otherArray)
```

If your intent was just to make a copy of the original array, though, I would  suggest using [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var otherArray = array.slice()

console.log(otherArray)
```